# Undefined phrases from annyang in callback result

Tags: javascript, annyang

I am using annyang library to my microphone, but I get undefined in my audio:

> I think the user said:  undefined
> But then again, it could be any of the following:  undefined

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/annyang/2.6.1/annyang.min.js"></script>
```

This is my code:

```js
if (annyang) {
            
    annyang.addCallback('result', function(phrases) {
        console.log("I think the user said: ", phrases);
        console.log("But then again, it could be any of the following: ", phrases);
    });

    annyang.start({ autoRestart: true});
            
}
```